# Двойная сортировка массива

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Есть массив компаний, для которых (перед показом массива пользователю) рассчитывается рейтинговый балл на основе выбранных в фильтре значений.

Элементы массива имеют такую структуру:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 10
        [NAME] => Наименование компании
        [BALL] => 5
)
[1] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 12
        [NAME] => Наименование компании
        [BALL] => 10
)
[2] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 3
        [NAME] => Наименование компании
        [BALL] => 15
)
```

После расчёта баллов (поле "BALL") массив прогоняется через пользовательскую функцию `customMultiSortArray()`:

```
function customMultiSortArray($array, $field) {
    $sortArr = array();
    foreach($array as $key=>$val) {
        $sortArr[$key] = $val[$field];
    }
    array_multisort($sortArr, $array);
    return $array;
}
```

Вызов функции осуществляется так:

```
$arResult["ITEMS"] = customMultiSortArray($arResult["ITEMS"], "BALL");
```

Всё сортируется прекрасно в порядке возрастания балла. Но иногда возникают ситуации, в которых у некоторых компаний одинаковое значение рейтингового балла. Тогда нужно сортировать компании с одинаковым баллом по алфавиту: вначале английские названия от `A....Z`, затем русские от `А....Я`. То есть картина должна быть такой:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 10
        [NAME] => AMD
        [BALL] => 10
)
[1] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 12
        [NAME] => Intel
        [BALL] => 10
)
[2] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 3
        [NAME] => НИИ Микроэлектроники
        [BALL] => 10
)
[3] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 8
        [NAME] => Следующая компания с большим значением балла
        [BALL] => 11
)
```

Можно как-то преобразовать `customMultiSortArray()`, или нужно делать сортировку отдельной функцией?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, собственно, решение. А  в функцию уж оформишь, надеюсь

```
$arr =  array( 
Array
    (
        'ID' => 10,
        'NAME' => "Наименование 5",
        'BALL' => 5
), 
 Array
    (
        'ID' => 12,
        'NAME' => "Наименование 10",
        'BALL' => 10,
),
 Array
    (
        'ID' => 33,
        'NAME' => "Имя 5",
        'BALL' => 5
),
 Array
    (
        'ID' => 3,
        'NAME' => "Наименование 15",
        'BALL' => 15
));

$cond = "BALL";
usort($arr, function ($a, $b) use($cond) 
             { return ($ret = $b[$cond] - $a[$cond]) ? $ret : strcmp($a[NAME], $b[NAME]); });
print_r($arr);
```

результат

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 3
            [NAME] => Наименование 15
            [BALL] => 15
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 12
            [NAME] => Наименование 10
            [BALL] => 10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 33
            [NAME] => Имя 5
            [BALL] => 5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 10
            [NAME] => Наименование 5
            [BALL] => 5
        )

)
```

Comment: Вроде работает, правда я asort() использовал, а то в вашем варианте функция задом-наперёд разворачивала массив.

Comment: просто a-b поменяй на b-a :)

Comment: вы знаете что-то не так работает или я где-то ошибаюсь и думаю что работает не так: `$raiting = array(
 array("NAME"=>"Promo", "BALL"=>10),
 array("NAME"=>"ADLABS", "BALL"=>10),
);
//asort($raiting);
//reset($raiting);


$cond = "BALL";
asort($raiting, function ($a, $b) use($cond) 
 { return ($ret = $b[$cond] - $a[$cond]) ? $ret : strcmp($a["NAME"], $b["NAME"]); });

echo "<pre>";
print_r($raiting);
echo "</pre>";` вобщем массив не сортируется, выводится в таком же порядке. А должен по идеи поставить элемент с именем "ADLABS" первым. Не знаете что-не так?

Comment: можно поконкретней? :) а то даже страшно подумать

Comment: извините не получается корретно код добавить в комментарий, с переносами он выглядит так http://joxi.ru/5mdkEJBcM1jar1 . Т.е. возникла ситуация когда 2 элемента с одинаковым колличеством баллов имеют разные имена. И сортировка по идеи должа переставить выше тот у которого имя в алфавитном порядке раньше. А оно что-то не хочет. При этом обычный asort() и reset() сортирует такой массив правильно. =(

Comment: первое, что стоит сделать, поменять `strcmp($a[NAME], $b[NAME])` на наоборот и посмотреть, поменяется ли порядок в результате

Comment: https://eval.in/386886 у меня usort там, я поменял в твоем коде одну букву , все работает

Comment: чувствую себя мягко выражаясь глупым, на примере простого массива действительно с usort() всё начинает работать как надо, но стоит ту же функуцию применить к полновестному массиву. получается лажа, сортировка идёт по баллам в обратном порядке http://joxi.ru/vAWDxaOsnVyRrW тут `strcmp($a[NAME], $b[NAME])` менял местами, реакции никакой .

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25147/discussion-between-maler1988-and-splash58).

Comment: Eckb порядок по баллам нужен другой, меняй наоборот `$ret = $b[$cond] - $a[$cond]` сравнение строк работает только при равенстве баллов